# Need help rigging a latch

Tags: rigging

I'’ve tried rigging this case latch but I’m having issues with it. Would appreciate if someone can help me out with it. Blend file will be provided.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really important to set the origins to the rigth place, where the parts are rotates. Then set the lock part (the wire) as a child of the latch and add a Track to constraint to it, which points the objetc's y axis to an empty. So when you rotate the latch, the lock's end will stay down. After you rise the latch, you have to move the empty above the model, to rise up the lock. You can just move the empty manually, or set it as a child of an other empty and rotate it.
[image]

https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/A08G7S9e

Comment: Thanks so much!. I mean, the answer was so simple before me and i couldn't see it!. You just saved my day. Gracias.